# Wordpress search not searching pages' content

Tags: search

My wordpress site doesnt search for pages' content. I have checked for the existence of the following filter that could prevent search from searching pages but there aint any

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','myfunction');
```

What else could I check for?
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Loveleen

Comment: Depending on the theme, I'm not sure Wordpress searches across pages by default. Try this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```